# Had this dashboard application working now some lines of code arent registering ..For starters Hover State Is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, dashboard

I was building a dashboard project (new to javascript) and for somereason some of my hover states are working and some are not...also i added a new event listener to do an alert just to see if it was working and something is wrong with that also...Anyfeed back on what this could be ..Hover state is working on buttons but not Usernames..

```js
const userNamesUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
const newsUrl =
  'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=9GZM26UeghzD7lATJGQAUfez8uJKRAB8'
const employeeButton = document.getElementById('employee')
const dataButton = document.getElementById('data-button')
const ulUserName = document.getElementById('usernames-list')
const homeButton = document.getElementById('home-button')

async function fetchJsonApiData() {
  const response = await fetch(userNamesUrl)
  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}

async function fetchNewsData() {
  const response = await fetch(newsUrl)
  const newsData = await response.json()
  return newsData
}

employeeButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  const dialog = document.createElement('dialog')
  //code so usernames do not re-render
  if (ulUserName.children.length > 1) {
    return
  }
  //capturing api data and configuring it into an array
  const data = await fetchJsonApiData()
  const userArray = Array.from(data)
  console.log(userArray)
  userArray.forEach((user) => {
    const userDiv = document.createElement('li')
    userDiv.classList.add('usernames')
    userDiv.innerText = user.name
    ulUserName.appendChild(userDiv)
    //creation of modal pop-up
    userDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.body.appendChild(dialog)
      dialog.showModal()
      //creating innerText of Modal
      const modalList = document.createElement('ul')
      modalList.classList.add('modal-list')
      const userName = document.createElement('li')
      userName.innerText = 'Name : ' + user.name
      const email = document.createElement('li')
      email.innerText = 'Email : ' + user.email
      const phoneNumber = document.createElement('li')
      phoneNumber.innerText = 'Phone : ' + user.phone
      const address = document.createElement('li')
      address.innerText =
        'Address : ' +
        user.address.street +
        ',' +
        user.address.suite +
        ',' +
        user.address.city +
        ',' +
        user.address.zip
      //appending  modal items to modal-list
      modalList.appendChild(userName)
      modalList.appendChild(email)
      modalList.appendChild(phoneNumber)
      modalList.appendChild(address)
      //adding a class to the modal-List items
      modalList.classList.add('modal-list')
      //append modal-list to dialog element
      dialog.appendChild(modalList)
    })
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #154551;
  --secondary-color: #00a1a7;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: larger;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 7.5% 1fr 1fr 1fr 7.5% 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.dash-container {
  padding: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.buttons {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  max-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button-padding {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

#logo-image {
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 40px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

input {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.buttons {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  max-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.usernames {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #000000;
}

.usernames:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(0, 161, 167);
}

ul {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  list-style: none;
}

dialog {
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px 0.5px black;
}

.modal-list {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dash-container" id="dash-container"></div>
    <button-padding></button-padding>
    <button-Grouping class="buttons">
      <button class="button" type="button" id="home-button">Home</button>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="employee">Employee's</button>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="calendar">Calendar</button>
      <button id="data-button" class="button" type="button">Data</button>
    </button-Grouping>
    <img src="images/diamondlogo.png" alt="" id="logo-image" />
    <ul id="usernames-list"></ul>
    <ul class="news-feed" id="news-feed"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```